# Convert dataset into combobox items using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I am trying to take a `DataSet` and add each item to a `ComboBox`.

I am currently using a `foreach` loop, like so:

```
 foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
 {
     cmbCauseForRepair.Items.Add(row[0].ToString() + ":" + row[1].ToString());
 }
```

I would like to do this using LINQ.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
     cmbCauseForRepair.Items.Add(from r in ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                              select r[0] + ":" + r[1]);
```

However, my `ComboBox` only has 1 item: "System.Linq.Enumerable".

Comment: All of the current answer do not deal with the real problem. The real problem. By using add range i now have 12 items that say System.Linq.Enumerable. #lovethedownvote

Comment: How did you use the `AddRange`?

Comment: cmbCauseForRepair.Items.AddRange()

Comment: The same code from above. Just change add to addrange. `cmbCauseForRepair.Items.AddRange(from r in ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>() select r[0] + ":" + r[1]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ isn't looping over the records for you.  You still need to do that.

If `cmbCauseForRepair.Items.Add()` had an overload which accepted an enumeration of values then you wouldn't need to.  But it doesn't.  It just accepts [an `object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  And according to that documentation, that object will be treated as:

> A visual representation of the item is displayed in the combo box. This content representation is specified by the DisplayMember property. If the DisplayMember property is null, the item's ToString method is called to obtain the string that is displayed in the combo box; otherwise, the property of the stored object as specified by the DisplayMember property is displayed.

Since the object being passed to `Add()` is of type `IEnumerable<string>` then the `.ToString()` representation of it is:

```
`IEnumerable<string>`
```

Basically, you need to loop through your objects to add them one at a time:

```
var items = from r in ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
            select r[0] + ":" + r[1];
foreach (var item in items)
    cmbCauseForRepair.Items.Add(item);
```

Or use [a different method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to add them:

```
cmbCauseForRepair.Items.AddRange(from r in ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                                 select r[0] + ":" + r[1]);
```

Comment: I upvoted and accepted your answer, but did not add a simple Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

`.Add()` only adds a single item.

Try the same approach, but use [`.AddRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange.aspx), which adds a collection of `Object`s to the `ComboBox`:

```
cmbCauseForRepair.Items.AddRange(from r in ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                                 select r[0] + ":" + r[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `string.Format` instead of concatenation string

```
cmbCauseForRepair.Items.AddRange(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(p => string.Format("{0}:{1}", p[0], p[1])).ToArray());
```